# How can I authenticate users on a CMS for an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, wordpress, authentication, content-management-system

I am working on an iPhone app which will fetch data (images + text) from a CMS. I had a look at the Wordpress CMS, but the app is subscription based. How should I go about authenticating the subscribers which are being directed to the cms?

Can anyone guide me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, and broad, perhaps if you broke it down a bit.

Are you using an iphone app, or a standard page with a Mobil browser?

If it's an standalone app are you having problems getting it to talk to your server/CMS?

You having problems authenticating https vs http?

If your having problems with your cms or are you after cms to start with?

From the sound of it Drupal could work well with the services module and probably Ubercart to handle the subscription. With zen (base theme) and some modifications** you can make it Mobil friendly.

http://drupal.org/start

http://drupal.org/project/services

http://drupal.org/project/ubercart

http://drupal.org/project/zen

** http://drupal.org/node/1008582